# Make a file never merge in bzr

Tags: merge, bazaar

**The situation:**

Several branches I constantly have to merge between them. Each branch has a special file that identifies the branch (with certain settings for commit mails, plugin options and more, doesn't matter here).

**The problem:**

Whenever I merge one branch to the other and this special file has been changed it will obviously overwrite the merge target file. But I don't want this to happen. Those files must be version controlled in their branches as they are an essential part of it, but they should not be merged at all as they contain branch specific information.

**The question:**

Is it possible (and how) to exclude a specific file from a merge? I'd like a solution that doesn't requier me to specify this on each merge as a paramter, but if there's nothing else then I bite the bullet.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to exclude a file from a merge is to revert it right after the merge, before you commit, for example:

```
cd /path/to/repo/trunk
bzr merge ../branchA
bzr revert file/to/exclude
bzr commit -m 'merged from branchA'
```

Later, when you merge again from `branchA`, the `bzr revert` step in the middle is only necessary if the file changed in `branchA` since the last merge. So if the file doesn't change very often, then "biting the bullet" might not be all that bad.

Comment: Well, yes, but that requires manual intervention every time. The point here is to avoid the trouble alltogether. We constantly merge certain files and have to revert them later.

Comment: It's not necessarily every time. For example if the file changes every  5 months, and you merge every month, then you will not need the extra step 80% of the time. If the file never changes you'll never need the extra step (after the initial merge). I understand your point, but I don't see another way.